# DNSServiceRegister Qt/C++ not found

Tags: c++, qt, service-discovery, zeroconf

I'm implementing a DNS Service Register (like Bonjour) with C++ & Qt.
I followed this tutorial : https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq23-bonjour.html

Here is the header file of the service discovery class :

```
#ifndef BONJOURSERVICEREGISTER_H
#define BONJOURSERVICEREGISTER_H

#include <QtCore/QObject>

#include "bonjourrecord.h"
#include <dns_sd.h>

class QSocketNotifier;

#include <dns_sd.h>

class BonjourServiceRegister : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
   BonjourServiceRegister(QObject *parent = 0);
   ~BonjourServiceRegister();

void registerService(const BonjourRecord &record, quint16      servicePort);
inline BonjourRecord registeredRecord() const {return finalRecord; }

signals:
   void error(DNSServiceErrorType error);
   void serviceRegistered(const BonjourRecord &record);

private slots:
   void bonjourSocketReadyRead();

private:
   static void DNSSD_API bonjourRegisterService(DNSServiceRef sdRef,  DNSServiceFlags, DNSServiceErrorType errorCode, const char *name, const char *regtype, const char *domain, void *context);
   DNSServiceRef dnssref;
   QSocketNotifier *bonjourSocket;
   BonjourRecord finalRecord;
};

#endif // BONJOURSERVICEREGISTER_H
```

But I got a problem when I compile I got this errors :

```
undefined reference to `DNSServiceRefDeallocate'
undefined reference to `DNSServiceRefSockFD'
undefined reference to `DNSServiceRegister'
```

I'm on linux. Do I have to link or include something?

Thank you

Comment: You need to install and link against `libdns_sd.so`.

Comment: Hi !
Thank you for your answer :)
I just added : LIBS += /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdns_sd.so in my .pro file and it seems to resolve the problem :)
I just have a warning "The program 'MyProgram' uses the Apple Bonjour compatibility layer of Avahi."
"Please fix your application to use the native API of Avahi!"

Do you know what to do ?

Comment: The problem is that the API you're using is *very* old.  The installed libraries support it for compatibility reasons but you should -- at some point -- move to the correct Avahi API as demonstrated [here](http://avahi.org/doxygen/html/client-publish-service_8c-example.html).